# Using Axios in HarmonyOS JS Framework for Wearables

Tags: axios, wearables, harmonyos

I'm using HarmonyOs to create a (not lite) Wearable App. I want to use Axios to send requests to my server.
I was able to install the package with `npm install axios` and `import` it on the page I want to use it.

The problem I'm facing is that the whole axios request seems to be ignored. Here is an example.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    onButtonClick() {
        console.log("AXIOS TEST")

        axios.get("https://example.com/test")
            .then(result => console.log("AXIOS result " + result))
            .catch(error => console.log("AXIOS error " + error))

        console.log("AXIOS TEST END")
    }
}
```

I get the `AXIOS TEST` and `AXIOS TEST END` logs when I click the button but neither the result nor error logs. Neither any other logs related to axios.

I believe I have the needed permissions and I tested this snippet in a `node` script and that worked fine.

Am I missing something or can someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As relevant team confirmed, axios is not supported currently, but is being planned.

Therefore, you are advised to preferentially use fetch requests.

For more details,pls kindly refer [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/doc-references/js-apis-network-data-request-0000000000626077).

Comment: Thanks @shirley. Ill accept the answer for now. Hopefully I will be able to add another answer in the future where Axios is available.